# How can i extend this recolor function?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, scrollbar

I create a recolor function to recolor my picture box,

my function works red, it turn everything to red.

But now i want to input some Scroll Bar function to control it.

if i want 3 scroll bars which represent R , G , B

how can i do that base on my current function?

```
    Try
        ' Retrieve the image.
        image1 = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Anons\Desktop\Winter.jpg", True)

        Dim x, y As Integer

        ' Loop through the images pixels to reset color.
        For x = 0 To image1.Width - 1
            For y = 0 To image1.Height - 1
                Dim pixelColor As Color = image1.GetPixel(x, y)
                Dim newColor As Color = _
                    Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 0, 0)
                image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor)
            Next
        Next

        ' Set the PictureBox to display the image.
        PictureBox1.Image = image1

        ' Display the pixel format in Label1.
        Label1.Text = "Pixel format: " + image1.PixelFormat.ToString()

    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error." _
            & "Check the path to the image file.")
    End Try
End Sub$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to multiply all three color components (R, G, and B) by a fractional factor which is determined by the scroll bar.  For instance, a factor of 1 would keep it the same color.  A factor of .5 would make the color half as bright.  A factor of 2 would make it twice as bright, etc.

```
Dim rFactor As Single = rScroll.Value / 100
Dim gFactor As Single = gScroll.Value / 100
Dim bFactor As Single = bScroll.Value / 100
Dim newColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R * rFactor, pixelColor.R * gFactor, pixelColor.B * bFactor)
```

Comment: do i declare these factors inside the function?

Comment: I already showed how they are declared in my example.  What part of the example are you having trouble understanding?